# download multiple files from ftp in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, download, ftp, blackraccoon

I am developing an app for an iPhone in Xcode 5. I want to download multiple files from the ftp server once a week only if they are changed. I am using performFetchWithCompletionHandler() and BlackRaccoon to download just one file. How can I download multiple files using BlackRaccoon and how can I check modified date of the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below one to download multiple files FTP, here is the link for the source code: https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest

Comment: Isn't this library only for http server? I want to download from ftp server.

Comment: I have changed the link, the above one is working fine for me with ftp server.

Comment: thanks, do you have any sample code for this library?

Comment: In the above link itself there is a sample code with explanation, I think you can follow it. if it is helpful for you, please tap on Up arrow on upper left corner.

Comment: @keshav i am using the above url which you have mentioned in your answer.I successfully created directory and uploaded images to that directory.Now in one view i am showing all images of that directory.If user clicks on images ,it should download that image on your phone.Now my problem is how to download the images.

Comment: - (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)ftpURL toDownloadFile:(NSString *)filePath;   how to pass filePath name and download it.

Answer (score 0):

[Go To this Link it may help you](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper)

```
- (void) downloadM_lFiles
```

{

```
  NSData *ftpM_lData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[FTPHelper sharedInstance].filePath];
}
```

For Modified date use [CFFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/CFFTPSample/Listings/CFFTPSample_c.html)
Please vote up if u get desired answer.